# How to use a for loop for multiple labels

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, for-loop, label

Im fairly new to this so a little help would be nice, so basically i have this form with 100 labels, i have a textbox where a value is to be entered into it. I need the first label to display the value of the textbox and the rest thereafter to display the value incremented until 100. I know how to do manually but that is 100 statements, i was wondering if there a way to use a for loop. Thanks in advance

Comment: What language? What have you tried? Perhaps you should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes, most likely there's a way to use a for loop. However, as you've failed to provide any information about the language you're using and no effort to accomplish anything yourself, it's impossible to be more specific as to how to do so. If you want help here, you need to provide sufficient information. We can't see your screen or read your mind, so all we have is the info you make available in your question.

Comment: Apologies , quite new to this site, in am using c#, my labels are name Label1  Label2 and sooo on

Comment: So what, are these labels on a web page, on a .NET form, to be printed out, etc? You still haven't given enough information for anyone to help you. It would probably help if you showed your current code.

Comment: sorry very new to this, ok i am making a windows form application with visual studio using c#, there is 100 labels and a textbox on it , so far thats it, currently all the label texts are clear, i want to change the text of the labels to numbers depending on the input of the textbox. Starting with that number and incrementing up to 100.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value;
        if (int.TryParse(this.textBox1.Text, out value))
        {
            var query =
                from index in Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                from label in this.Controls
                    .OfType<Label>()
                    .Where(x => x.Name == "label" + (index + 1))
                select new { label, index };

            foreach (var x in query)
            {
                x.label.Text = (value + x.index).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```